# how to link to an official account from the built-in browser

Tags: wechat

From an official account main menu view I can provide a URL and it will open in the built in WeChat browser.

Is there a way to close the browser and come back to the main account menu?

I don't want to have the user hit the [X] button each time.

Is there a standard URL format for an official account that can be used as a link to open the account from a browser?

Answer (score 0):

In short, there's no way to do that.

In early days, there are some hacking ways to do this, but now they are all not working any more.

You can put a qrcode image of your account on your site for users to scan and follow you.